# meteor: app doesn't work on meteor site (deploy)

Tags: meteor, meteorite, meteor-blaze

I'm writing a meteor app, which used to work great on the meteor.com site

```
$> mrt deploy myapp.meteor.com
```

However, for a couple of days now, the application doesn't work anymore (it still works local!)
In the console I now get the following error

```
Exception in defer callback: Error: Oh no! No route found for path: "/"
at o.extend.onRouteNotFound
```

Which is weird, because I have a route defined:

```
Router.configure({
    layout: 'layout',
    loadingTemplate: 'loading',
    notFoundTemplate: 'notFound'
});
Router.map(function () {
    this.route('/', {
        controller: 'HomeController'
    });
});
```

And the controller looks like this:

```
HomeController = RouteController.extend({
    template: 'layout',

    onBeforeAction: function () {
        // TODO
    },
    waitOn: function () {
        return [App.subs.lanes, App.subs.taskColors];
    },
    start: function () {},
    action: function () {
        if (this.ready())
            this.render();
        else
            ;
    }
});
```

I just updated meteorite, and updated the project

```
% mrt update
✓ scss
   tag: https://github.com/fourseven/meteor-scss.git#v0.8.4
✓ iron-router
   tag: https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router.git#v0.7.1
✓ blaze-layout
   tag: https://github.com/EventedMind/blaze-layout.git#v0.2.4
```

But still with the same result, local is everything working but the deployment app gives the route error. Maybe it helps, but here are the versions of mrt and meteor

```
% mrt --version
Meteorite version 0.7.3
Release 0.8.0
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: I'm not sure it's valid to have a layout as the `template` for your route. What happens if you replace it with a template that doesn't contain a `yield`?

Comment: Found the problem, the route definition is wrong, if I add 'home' as the first arguments and the other stuff in a hash it works again !!